# How to add a script using Connect to a network dialog in Vista

Tags: configuration, remote-access

Years ago, using RAS, I was able to add a script to run external programs and configure settings after connecting to a network such a VPN.

I cannot find now that option in Vista UI neither in XP.

I think this is still possible, but it was discouraged from MS but for me is useful to set some routes through the new connection.

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didnt know [rasdial command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490979.aspx), then I can use a normal batch to connect with rasdial and set my other configuration values at that time

Thanks all for your help